# Nested Resorces :forbdden attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new in rails and I am getting `ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError`. This is my controller for nested resource:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  def index
    @post=Post.all  
  end

  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.build
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def create
    debugger
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.build(params[:post])
    if @post.save
      redirect_to user_posts_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, {:user_ids =>[]})
  end
end
```

Comment: First of all, you are not passing post_params in your controller action. and when using build, you should use params like following:params.require(:user).permit(posts_attributes => [:title, :description]) and if you will have nested form for user and posts, you will get proper params.

Comment: What do your params look like?

Comment: Please post your models.

Comment: class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :posts
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :posts, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: proc { |bar| bar[:title].blank? }
end

Comment: I would like to see your `form code` and the `params` generated in the `log` when you submit the form.Please post them.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following models:

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

You don't actually need to use nested attributes, just do the following in your controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  def index
    @post = Post.all  
  end

  def new
    @post = Post.new
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @post = @user.posts.new(post_params) # This will automatically set user_id in the post object

    if @post.save
      redirect_to user_posts_path
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
```

Although I don't recommend that you user a **user_id** param in the url. Have a look at the [devise gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) to handle authentication.